# SWT browser view page source

Tags: java, browser, view, swt

I am using SWT browser in my application
I have edited SWT source code according to my need, Now I want a feature of view web page source code by click on button
I have managed "Go to Home page " like this

```
public void goHome() {
    int[] rgdispid = auto.getIDsOfNames(new String[]{"GoHome"}); 
    int dispIdMember = rgdispid[0];
    auto.invoke(dispIdMember);
}
```

I want to know if there is any string for "view page source" like "GoHome"
Or is there any other way to do this.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Based on the API of the SWT Browser, looks like you can get the HTML of the page by calling the getText() method.
[Eclipse SWT Browser API](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/browser/Browser.html#getText%28%29)